# How can I :hover over different links in one line while getting the spacing correct?

Tags: css, class, hover

I have the top bar of my page set up as follows: Home | Contact Us etc..
It lies within a p tag inside a div id.
How would i go about setting up the :hover css on each link without having to separate them into different classes such as how I have them at the moment. Is it possible? 
I don't think i used the correct css because i couldn't position them correctly without having to use different padding parameters for each class which makes the spacing look inaccurate.

via codepen: http://codepen.io/Hafkamp/pen/jabmE

html:

```
<div id="topinfo">
<div class="home"><p>Home |</p></div> 
<div class="about"><p>About |</p></div> 
<div class="contactUs"><p>Contact Us |</p></div> 
<div class="map"><p>Map |</p></div> 
</div><!--/topinfo tag-->
```

css:

```
.home p{padding-right:250px;}
#topbar .home p:hover{color:rgba(255,255,255,1)}
```

Is there an easier way to do this that is not so tedious. This method also causes the divider to have the hover effect which is not desirable.

Comment: Why not *show* us your (relevant / **[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**) HTML instead of describing it to us ambiguously?

Comment: Your codepen doesn't seem to match what you're saying. Those cells (none of which are "Contact Us", despite your description) highlight independently of each other in my browser.

Comment: There is a Contact Us. And the hover feature is working. I was just wondering if there is an easier way to set it up.

Comment: My mistake. I was looking at the #navbar. I didn't even see the black bar at the top. I'd suggest adjusting the colors on it to make it more visible, but that's a different issue.

Comment: Yea, the colors don't concern me too much atm. It's just the way i set it up which bothers me.. as you can see the padding on each class is quite random and the divider also highlights on the hover which looks kind of silly.

Comment: Much easier to use a right border on the `p` tag than a `pipe` character...and you can control the color with CSS.

Comment: Thanks I used your tip for the border. I think there might be more spacing on the right than the left of the characters but so far it seems much more handy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give them all the same class, say `topitem`, and use a rule like this:

```
.topitem:hover p {
  color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Although really, I would get rid of the interior `<p>` tag and reduce the selector to `.topitem:hover` – the text is already wrapped in a `<div>`, so why wrap it again? (But see Zinnia's note about the convention of using `<ul>` and `<li>` instead of nested `<div>`s.)

Comment: Rated your answer the best because you were right about not needing a separate div just for the text i was using and yeah ul li's make much more sense, thus eliminating the need for p tags. revised code http://codepen.io/Hafkamp/pen/jabmE Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

The best way of defining menus in a page is to use "ul" and "li"  tags. But if you still want to use with

tag you have to use it this way: 
`Home

About

contact

.home_link, .about_link, .contact_link{color: red;}
.home_link:hover, .about_link:hover, .contact_link:hover {color: blue;}`

Comment: Thanks, I have changed it to ul li style. Much more convenient!!